# Double limit and dominated convergence theorem

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, analysis, convergence-divergence

I am interested in the double limit of a particular function $f_m(x,\varepsilon)$ of the form
$$f_m(x,\varepsilon) = \frac{1}{m}\sum_{n=0}^{m-1}g(x,\varepsilon).$$
I want to compute
$$\lim_{\varepsilon \to 0}\lim_{m\to \infty}\frac{1}{m}\sum_{n=0}^{m-1}g_n(x,\varepsilon).$$
Without the $1/m$ normalisation the limit reduces to
$$\lim_{\varepsilon \to 0}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}g_n(x,\varepsilon)$$
where $|g_n(x,\varepsilon)|\leq h_n(x)$ where $\sum_{n=0}^\infty h_n(x)$ does not necessarily converge for all choices of $x$.

My question is the following. Knowing that $\lim_{m\to \infty} \frac{1}{m}\sum_{n=0}^{m-1}h_n(x)$ converges for almost every $x$, are we allowed to say that
$$\lim_{\varepsilon \to 0}\lim_{m\to \infty}\frac{1}{m}\sum_{n=0}^{m-1}g_n(x,\varepsilon)=\lim_{\varepsilon \to 0}\lim_{m\to \infty}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{m}g_n(x,\varepsilon)$$
and apply dominated convergence here by arguing that $|\frac{1}{m}g_n(x,\varepsilon)|\leq \frac{1}{m}h_n(x)$ where now in the dominated convergence theorem we are interested in whether $\lim_{m\to \infty} \frac{1}{m}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}h_n(x)$ converges which we know it does by assumption? Is my idea nonsense?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this doesn't work in general. Consider as a counter-example :
$$
g_n(x,\varepsilon) := e^{-1/(n+1)\varepsilon},
\ \ \ \
h_n(x) := 1.
$$
We directly have $g_n\leq h_n$, and so $\limsup_{m\to\infty} \frac{1}{m} \sum_{n=0}^{m-1} g_n(x,\varepsilon) \leq 1$.
Furthermore, for any $\varepsilon>0$ and small $\delta>0$, there is an $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $1-\delta< g_n(x,\varepsilon)\leq 1$ for all $n\geq N$, and so :
$$
\frac{1}{m}\sum_{n=0}^{m-1} g_n(x,\varepsilon)
= \underbrace{\frac{1}{m}\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} g_n(x,\varepsilon)}_{\geq 0}
+ \underbrace{\frac{1}{m}\sum_{n=N}^{m-1} g_n(x,\varepsilon)}_{\geq \frac{m-N}{m}(1-\delta)}
\Longrightarrow
\liminf_{m\to\infty} \frac{1}{m}\sum_{n=0}^{m-1} g_n(x,\varepsilon) \geq 1-\delta.
$$
Taking $\delta\to 0$, we get $\lim_{m\to\infty} \frac{1}{m}\sum_{n=0}^{m-1} g_n(x,\varepsilon) = 1$.

However, taking the limit in $\varepsilon$ first, we have $\lim_{\varepsilon\to0} g_n(x,\varepsilon)=0$, and so the limits can't be swapped.